# Integrate facebook connect/ twitter with jquery mobile

Tags: facebook, jquery, twitter, jquery-mobile

I am currently developing the mobile version of my site.

Can you please give me a tutorial to integrate Facebook connect / Twitter so users can connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help you : http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1239874936/facebook-login-on-iphone-phonegap

Answer (score 1):

This blog post http://www.wisejive.com/2010/11/phonegap-jquery-mobile-twitter-and.html contains the detail answer for both facebook connect and twitter. Of course, as the blogger mentions he is extending on the technique provided at http://www.pushittolive.com/post/1239874936/facebook-login-on-iphone-phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid phonegap, this solution is pretty neat - http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-social-media-share-plugin-jsshare/

Otherwise, the newer phonegap friendly solution uses their plugins directly, which can leverage some native apps and avoid the difficulties of OAuth - https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect & https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS